# How can I remove empty space between stacked sections of a bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I am using plotly and ggplot2 to create an interactive stacked bar chart to identify which bee_species (y axis) are attracted to specific plant_species (x axis).

However, my stacked bars have these empty spaces in them that do not correspond to a bee_species, and I can't seem to find a way to get rid of them. Can someone help me understand why these are showing up and how I can get rid of these spaces?

Bar chart of bee_species per plant_species

[image: chart]

Here is my code to clean up the data and make the bar chart I showed. I have looked into the documentation for plotly and ggplot with no luck at finding any explanation for the gaps in my bar chart.

```
#importing libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

#cleaning up the data
data <- data %>% 
    filter(plant_species != "None", bee_species != "None", nonnative_bee != "null") %>% 
    select(-c("species_num","site","sampling","specialized_on","status"))

native_bee_data <- data %>%
    filter(nonnative_bee == 0) %>%
    group_by(sample_id, plant_species)

nonnative_bee_data <- data %>% 
    filter(nonnative_bee == 1) %>%
    group_by(sample_id, plant_species)

#Attempting to visualize how many species of bees were attracted to each plant species

ggplotly(
  ggplot(native_bee_data, aes(x = plant_species, fill = bee_species, stat = "count")) +
    geom_bar(position = "stack") + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust=1)) +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Bee Species")) +
    labs(title = "Number of Native Bee Species Attracted to Each Plant Species")
)
```

This is a truncated version of the DataFrame created when I filter native_bee_data for "Trifolium pratense". The bar chart leaves out Hylaeus modestus from the overall count:

| sample_id | plant_species | bee_species | nonnative_bee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17429 | Trifolium pratense | Bombus bimaculatus | 0 |
| 17429 | Trifolium pratense | Bombus bimaculatus | 0 |
| 17429 | Trifolium pratense | Bombus bimaculatus | 0 |
| 17429 | Trifolium pratense | Bombus bimaculatus | 0 |
| 17429 | Trifolium pratense | Bombus bimaculatus | 0 |
| 17433 | Trifolium pratense | Bombus bimaculatus | 0 |
| 17437 | Trifolium pratense | Bombus griseocollis | 0 |
| 17441 | Trifolium pratense | Bombus bimaculatus | 0 |
| 17441 | Trifolium pratense | Bombus bimaculatus | 0 |
| 17441 | Trifolium pratense | Bombus bimaculatus | 0 |
| 17441 | Trifolium pratense | Bombus bimaculatus | 0 |
| 17445 | Trifolium pratense | Bombus bimaculatus | 0 |
| 17445 | Trifolium pratense | Bombus bimaculatus | 0 |
| 17445 | Trifolium pratense | Bombus bimaculatus | 0 |
| 17445 | Trifolium pratense | Bombus bimaculatus | 0 |
| 17452 | Trifolium pratense | Lasioglossum coreopsis | 0 |
| 17461 | Trifolium pratense | Hylaeus modestus | 0 |
| 17465 | Trifolium pratense | Calliopsis andreniformis | 0 |
| 17465 | Trifolium pratense | Lasioglossum hitchensi | 0 |
| 17473 | Trifolium pratense | Halictus poeyi/ligatus | 0 |
| 17473 | Trifolium pratense | Bombus impatiens | 0 |

Comment: Can you please include some sample data we can load to reproduce the issue? For instance `library(dplyr); dput(native_bee_data |> filter(plant_species == "Trifolium repens")` should create code showing the data behind one of the plant species with missing bars.

Comment: I did do some investigation of that specific plant species within native_bee_data, and this data frame does include the bee species that are left out of the bar chart. Plus, when I remove the call to ggplotly, there are no gaps in the bar chart anymore. So, something seems to be wrong with the actual plot itself when I use ggplotly.